# How to stop my search function from checking cases (Uppercase/lowercase) - Javascript/ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a search function in ReactJS. My search function is working fine , but it is checking cases(Uppercase/lowercase). This is my Demo [Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7nx7q6v45). You can check the search functionality. I want to get rid of the case checking(Uppercase/lowercase). How should I change the code in the easiest manner?

This is my Search function

```
getMatchedList(searchText) {
    console.log('inside getMatchedList');
    if (searchText === ''){
      this.setState({ data: this.state.dataDefault });
    }
    if (!TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText)) {//Typechecker is a dependency
      console.log('inside if block');
      const res = this.state.dataDefault.filter(item => {
        return item.firstName.includes(searchText) || item.lastName.includes(searchText);
      });
      console.log('res' + JSON.stringify(res));

      this.setState({ data: res });
    }
  }
```

If I remove Typechecker dependency, how should I change the code? I basically want my search function to be case case insensitive

Comment: do you mean that you want your search to be case sensitive or case insensitive?

Comment: @quirimmo case insensitive

Comment: @quirimmo Can you help me to reconstruct the function to make it case insensitive

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is converting both the strings which needs to be compared to a lower case using a javascript's method  **toLowerCase()**. So just compare in a if condition,
           **if(item.firstName.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase())**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toLowerCase

```
if (!TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText)) {
  console.log("inside if block");
  const res = this.state.dataDefault.filter(item => {
    if (
      item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
      item.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    )
      return item;
  });
  console.log(res);

  this.setState({ data: res });
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/5yj23zmp34

Comment: @tommy123 Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/6ywl36m2n I was going to post the solution but aseferov beat me to it lol

Comment: @aseferov Will this work if I type in all caps/all small?

Comment: @AndrewL Will this work if I type in all caps/all small?

Comment: guys are you testing the solutions you are providing?

Comment: Yes. Open the forked fiddle above and try searching for sm5 or am2 or m3 and it will query it accordingly.

Comment: @quirimmo No. The solution provided by aseferov above and the forked fiddle I provided are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

With `ReactTable` you can filter out directly through the table props.

When you define your table accessors, you can define them in the following way:

```
{
  Header: "Name",
  columns: [
    {
      Header: "First Name",
      accessor: "firstName",
      filterMethod: (filter, row) =>
      row[filter..toUpperCase().includes(filter.value.toUpperCase())
    },
    {
      Header: "Last Name",
      id: "lastName",
      accessor: "lastName",
      filterMethod: (filter, row) => row[filter.id].toUpperCase().includes(filter.value.toUpperCase())
     }
   ]
 },
```

As you can see the `filterMethod` will do the filter for you.

And then, you can completely remove your `getMatchedList` function (so you get rid also of `TypeChecker` as you want to).

The case insensitive is made checking the values using `toUpperCase()` (you can even use `toLowerCase()`) which will give you the case insensitive.

Here your fork:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0x6wwpo15

Comment: I am implementing custom search box